# Partition of at most countable set is at most countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be any at most countable set. I have to prove that partition of at most countable set is at most countable set. It seems bvious, but I need formal proof.

Let $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ be partition of $X$. Since $X$  is at most countable, we can order its elements in a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. Any set in $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ is non empty, so it contains some elements of $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. For every $S_i$ we choose element $x_k\in S_i$ that has lowest index number $k$ among all elements in $S_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quicker method, depending on previous knowledge.

Define $f(x)=i$, if and only if $x\in S_i$. Then $f$ is a surjective function from $X$ onto $I$. Since the image of at most countable set is at most countable, $I$ is at most countable as well.

---

I qualified this being quicker, since in *most* cases you will learn that the image of at most countable set is at most countable, before you will see this sort of assertion. So we can reduce it to surjections.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, but the ending should read "thus the partition is in bijective correspondence with a subset of a set that is at most countable, hence is at most countable."